Femenino de nuncio

nuncio
Del lat. nuntius.

m. Encargado de llevar aviso, noticia o encargo de una persona a otra, enviado a esta para tal efecto.

m. Representante diplomático del papa, que ejerce además, como legado, ciertas facultades pontificias.

m. Anuncio o señal. El viento del sur suele ser en Madrid nuncio de lluvia.



Lo que aparece en el DLE. Por qué solo masculino? Aclaro que no sé nada del papa ni de cómo funciona la Iglesa Católica así que pregunto desde la ignorancia. Pero estaba leyendo un libro en donde se usaba el término y cuando lo busco en el diccionario y veo que es masculino me pregunto si el día de mañana nombran a una mujer para desempeñar la misma tarea sería una nuncia? O bien es un caso en el que el femenino es irregular como el de rey/reina? O bien sería un disparate que exista una mujer en ese cargo y entonces sería otro ‘término machista’ más?

Hombre, algo sí sabrás del Papa, no? Que es argentino al menos ;-P Que haya una "nuncia" tiene más o menos las mismas posibilidades de que haya una mujer en el cargo de Papa o de "obispa": muy pocas. Si existiere alguna vez, supongo que la RAE actualizará la entrada.

Pero falta todavía explicar cómo es posible que la primera acepción sea solo masculina. Es un duplicado de la segunda?

Quizás debería estar marcada esa primera acepción como des. (desusado). ¿No sería equivalente a mensajero/a o repartidor/a actualmente?

@Sofronias Qué interesante, a ver, contame más. Es la primera vez que veo la palabra y en un libro, ni siquiera oral. Dónde está la prueba de que en Argentina se sigue usando??

@Sofronias - Si echas un vistazo a mi respuesta, si bien no pude encontrar ese texto, sí encontré otro poema que alude a la diosa griega del arcoiris con la palabra nuncia.

@Sofronias ¿Nuncio se utiliza como equivalente a "mensajero" en Argentina?

@Sofronias Se ve que en la zona de tac no se usa tanto ;-P Lo contrastaré cuando tenga oportunidad con un par de compañeros argentinos que hay en mi empresa. En cualquier caso, en España sí está desusada esa primera acepción.

@Sofronias Pero tac ya hace referencia al diccionario y es hispanohablante nativo, creo que toda esa parte del side note sobra. Alguna referencia actual en lenguaje coloquial a "nuncio" como "mensajero" ayudaría a respaldar su afirmación.

@Sofronias me refiero a side note. Incluso si no es español, podrían ser muchas palabras más como tincho, conservadora, gataflorismo que ni aparecen en el diccionario. Lo que quiero decir es, según lo que entiendo tu argumento para side note es: está mal usarlo porque no aparece en el diccionario. Ahora, tu argumento para nuncia es: el femenino existe aunque no aparezca en los diccionarios ?? Entonces, uso o no uso una palabra aunque no aparezca en el diccionario? Por qué no te vas del sitio de una buena vez si solo venís a romper las bolas?

Nuncia
Se trata de un simple calco del vocablo latín medieval "nuncius", el cual a su vez era una mutación de una palabra romana mas antigua, es decir, nūntius. Todas estas palabras compartían el mismo significado, el de mensajero o mensajera, y tanto la forma medieval como su prededecesora clásica tenían sus declinaciones femeninas, nuncia y nūntia. Por lo tanto, la voz "nuncia" sería más que adecuada, aunque no existieran registros de su uso en español.
Sin embargo, sí existen.
Por ejemplo, el doctor Andrés Quintana Roo, personaje clave de la Revolución Mexicana que le dio su nombre al estado actual de Quintana Roo, escribió lo siguiente en su poema La libertad y la tiranía


Vino del aura leve conducida/
Desde la isla de Bética ensalzada/
Mas por ser de las Cortes cuna ilustre,/
Que por todas sus célebres batallas./
Al ver la Libertad, llegar la nuncia/
De heroicos hechos, de ínclitas hazañas,/
A escuchar las mayores, mas gloriosas/
Su enagenado espíritu prepara.

El conocido escritor español Graciliano Afonso personificó la violeta como la mensajera, o nuncia, de la primavera en Idilio: La violeta:

¡Oh Nuncia de la dulce primavera!/¡Oh violeta la imagen verdadera/De
un corazón modesto y virtuoso!/Desde el seno del céspede mullido/Dejas
al bosque henchido/De tu suave perfume delicioso./

Asimismo, en El Deucalion el conde español Alonso Verdugo de Castilla escribió de Iris, la emisaria de la diosa Hera:


La vaga nuncia de la eterea Juno/ tiende el gayado manto; el sol
renace.

Es obvio, entonces, que lo adecuado es usar "nuncia" tanto para la primera acepción dada en la pregunta como para la tercera; en cuanto a la segunda, esta no es más que un caso especial de la primera que se restringe al contexto católico. Cuando el Papa decida nombrar a una monja como emisaria, que a diferencia de lo que afirman algunos comentarios, es más probable a que haya un papa mujer (¿una mema?) porque no existe ninguna doctrina infalible contra las mujeres como emisarias como es el caso de los sacerdotes, lo más seguro es que va a llamarla nuncia de la iglesia y no nuncio ni otra cosa.

Inventar palabras por si algún día se pueden utilizar parece antieconómico (incluso tratándose del idioma analítico de John Wilkins, al que Borges critica). Así que tiene sentido que la acepción 2 sea solo en masculino.
Pero, atención, el Papa sopesa nombrar a Sor Lucía Caram portavoz del Vaticano o “Nuncia” en España.

Buen hallazgo ese enlace! +1

Actualmente, no hay mujeres que ocupen el cargo de nuncio en la Iglesia Católica.
El término "nuncio" se refiere a un representante diplomático del Papa, y tradicionalmente, este cargo ha sido ocupado exclusivamente por hombres, ya que los nuncios suelen ser arzobispos, y la Iglesia Católica no ordena mujeres como obispos.
Si alguna vez se nombrara a una mujer para desempeñar un papel similar, es probable que se necesitara una actualización en el lenguaje y en las normas eclesiásticas. Sin embargo, hasta ahora, no existe un equivalente femenino para el término "nuncio" en la práctica actual de la Iglesia Católica.
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuncio_apostólico

La primera acepción del vocablo no tiene nada que ver con la iglesia, y bien podría referirse a una mujer. La respuesta de Obie es la correcta.

@Bardo: No hace falta mencionarlo. Debería ser obvio que responde a la pregunta específica de tac sobre el significado 2.
